# compute time series weighted average

Tags: matlab, weighted-average

I have a `8760x1` vector with the 1-hour average ambient temperature time series.

**I want to calculate the weighted average temperature weighted by the percentage of operating
hours at each temperature level.**

What i thought is divide the temperature range with:

`ceil(Tmax-Tmin)`

and then use `hist`.

Are there any other suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you describe is not a weighted average. read in [wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_average) - though that's not what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean(temperatures)` should do it.

Since you have hourly measurements, the frequency of a given value will be reflecting the operating hours at that temperature level. A value that occurs frequently will therefore automatically have more weight in the average.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two vectors that are the same length, one is the temperature (temp), and the other is the amount of time at that temperature (time_at_temp).  The weighted average formula is this:

```
wt_avg_temp = sum(temp .* time_at_temp) / sum(time_at_temp);
```